# Integer palindrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

```
x = int(input())
if x<0 and (x%10 == 0 and x !=0):
    print("false")
rev = 0
while x>0:
    rev = rev*10 + x%10
    x = x // 10
if rev == x:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Since the reversed number is the same as entered one, the condition `rev == x` should return true but it's giving the opposite. What am I doing wrong?

Edit 1: converting to string is not allowed

---

Edit 2:   I see now.

Comment: why are you calculating stuff here? simpy compare `r = input(); r  == r[::-1]`?

Comment: Your `while` loops modifies `x`, so it no longer has the original input value. It exits as `0`

Comment: @PatrickArtner maybe string conversion isn't in the spirit of the problem

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

```
x = int(input())
```

You are reading `x` by `input()`, so a better idea to check if it's palindrome would  be reversing it:

```
x = input()
if (x == x[::-1]):
    ...
```

To better understand `[::-1]` I would suggest you to read [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931095/15888601).

---

Answer:

> *Your while loops modifies x, so it no longer has the original input value. It exits as 0*

Somebody in the comments said this, which is your real problem.

```
while x>0:
    rev = rev*10 + x%10
    x = x // 10
```

To be clearer I would suggest you to read this part of your code, and to wonder what will be the value of `x` at the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: Well this might not work. For example one might input `010` and if reversed seems to be a palindrome but in the integer world, that is not a palindrome

Comment: @KU99, you are right, it should be solved by adding x = str(int(x)).

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the 'x' value inside the while loop, irrespective of the input x equals 0 after the while loop.

Copy x value to some temp variable after the input() and compare that in the if condition.

```
x = 121
x1=x
if x<0 and (x%10 == 0 and x !=0):
    print("false")
rev = 0
while x>0:
    rev = rev*10 + x%10
    x = x // 10
#print(x1,rev)
if rev == x1:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```